# Can Japan visa holders go to South Korea?

Tags: indian-citizens, south-korea

I am a student in Japan and I want to visit South Korea in April. What documents do I need for that?

And can Indian passport holders in Japan enter Korea using a transit visa?

Comment: Look for your closest SK consulate/embassy.

Comment: Curious why you would even imagine that would be possible.

Comment: @Nick I suppose the OP thought the 30-day exemption applied to Japan too.

Answer (score 1):

A Japanese visa doesn't give you special rights in Korea (unlike, say, a US, Canadian or Australian visa). You are not eligible for the 30-day exemption.

You'll have to apply for a visa in one of the Korean consulates in Japan if you want to visit.

Comment: What documents required for get a sk visit visa for Indian students from Japan.,..flight ticket and return ticket is must???

Comment: Ask the Korean consulate in Minami Azabu...